# What does the pattern ～たりはしない do?

Tags: grammar

I keep seeing the pattern [`～たりはしない`](http://eow.alc.co.jp/%E3%81%9F%E3%82%8A%E3%81%AF%E3%81%97%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84/UTF-8/) and wondering what how the nuance/meaning is different from other forms. For example, how would the following sentences differ?

> "誰にも話したりはしない" and "誰にも話さない"
> "I won't tell anyone."
>
> "諦めたりはしないで" and "諦めないで"
> "Don't give up."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is たり as we know it, indicating an incomplete list of actions, in this case with a single example.

Your first example would be like the difference between "I won't tell anyone or anything" or the direct "I won't tell anyone", in English. The second example is similar - I won't include it here since it happens to sound less natural translated to English than the first.